# How to Retrieve/Decrypt DeviceCode from DeviceCodes Table on IdentityServer4

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using IdentityServer 4 - Device Flow as my authentication mechanism.

All the authentication is working fine.

I'm now trying to "Register" the device on the identity server Activation controller where you can add a name for the device.

Does anyone know how to Retrieve/Decrypt DeviceCode from DeviceCodes Table?

I would like to use this ID with a SignalR system at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom IDeviceFlowCodeService and implementing it that way.